# React: MUI Empty Icon to reserve space

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Sometimes I'd like an icon (e.g., end adornment for input) to be an empty icon, that I then replace with a real one at some point. Having the empty icon prevents a weird shift when the icon is added, by reserving the space.

I couldn't find a blank/empty icon in the MUI icons list though. What would be a good way to get an empty icon that behaves like a normal icon (with sizing and such)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out it's really simple. You can just use the `Icon` component, without giving it any children.

If you need to reserve the space for an `IconButton`, pass it the empty `Icon` and disable the button.